# force facebook like button to use fan_count as counter?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to force the facebook like button to use the fan_count as counter? And also like/unlike (increase/decrease the fan_count) when clicked? I have been browsing forums and read most tutorials but i wasnt able to get my question answered. It seems like the standard like button uses something complete different.

Comment: forced on anything is prohibited at every where ?? be aware ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to configure a Facebook URL as URL source to the Like Button, such as https://www.facebook.com/nike

Then, you're able to like the Page via the Like Button, see  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button